# custom directive onkeypress not working Angular 8

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

*my custom directive not working for onkeypress , I want to just allow numbers as a input , keyboard should't allow alphabits , it does't give any error and at the same time it does't work *

```
  <input OnlyNumber #focus type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="financialYear"/>
```

**only-number.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[OnlyNumber]"
})
export class OnlyNumberDirective {
  @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"]) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
    if (
      [
        "Delete",
        "Backspace",
        "Tab",
        "Escape",
        "Enter",
        "NumLock",
        "ArrowLeft",
        "ArrowRight",
        "End",
        "Home",
        "."
      ].indexOf(e.key) !== -1 ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.key === "a" && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.key === "c" && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+V
      (e.key === "v" && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.key === "x" && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey))
    ) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if (
      e.shiftKey ||
      ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"].indexOf(e.key) === -1
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `type="number"` if you want only numeric input. However it won't stop user from typing alphabets.

Comment: I want to do it via type="text" and user should't be able to enter non-numeric input

Comment: Your directive is working in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-form-7uypz9). Also you don't need `let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;`, the event passed in already a keyboard event. You could just say `onKeyDown(e)`.

Comment: I think you haven't import the directive to app module

Comment: I have already added it in app.module but not working

Comment: i am using directive into another module not in app.module.Actually my application has different modules . Should I import directive to specific module ?

Comment: You have to export that directive (Add that directive into **declarations** and **exports**)

Comment: @NoOne: Declare the directive in the module where you'd like to use it.

Comment: Check this link [link](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)